# FailedPreconditionError while using tensorlfow.metrics.recall

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use `tensorlfow.metrics.recall` and `tensorlfow.metrics.precision` but tensorflow raises `FailedPreconditionError`. Note that I have used `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]])
y_pred = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]])

predictions = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[3, 3])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[3, 3])
prec = tf.metrics.precision(labels, predictions)
rec = tf.metrics.recall(labels, predictions)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    p, r = sess.run([prec, rec], feed_dict={predictions: y_pred, labels: y_true})
    print("precision: {}, recall: {}".format(p, r))
```

- tensorflow version: 1.2.1
- python version: 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.metrics.precision` and `tf.metrics.recall` internally creates `local variable`(a variable which was created with `collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES]`). So you need to do : `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` as well.

Comment: it works, thanks. btw, why not just create one function that initialize **all** variables (both local and global)? what's the design concern here to separate local variables from global ones?

Comment: just found out there is such function `tf.initialize_all_variables`.

Comment: `tf.initialize_all_variables` is deprecated. You should use the above one.